# How can I complete my Histogram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to make Histogram, so far I have reached at following code would you please help me, where is the problem and how can I complete this task?

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    scale only axis,
    xmode=number,
    ymode=number,
    ybar interval,
    x tick label as interval=false,
    xtick={},
    xtickten={117.5, 126.5,135.5,144.5,153.5,162.5,171.5,180.5},
    yticklabel={},
    xmin=0, xmax=180.5,
    ymin=0,ymax=16,
    grid=none,
    ymajorgrids,
    log origin=infty
    ]
    \addplot [fill=gray!50] table [x=Lower, y=Count] {
        Lower Upper    Count
        117.5 126.5      4
        126.5 135.5      6
        135.5 144.5      10
        144.5 153.5     12
        153.5 162.5      4
        162.5 171.5      3
        171.5 180.5      1

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, what are you trying to achieve? I'm not sure about what changes you're trying to apply.

Comment: Is the problem the error you get when you compile?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not clear *how* the task should be completed.

Comment: If you remove the `xmode` and `ymode` lines it compiles properly